No implementations of interface io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver found that accept connection options io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions
I am having an issue with the native compilation of Quarkus. I am using the MySQLDriver to dynamically connect to MySQL databases, but this does not work with the native compilation.
Here is a simple version of the code in question:
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    Vertx vertx;

    private Pool getPool() {
        var options = new MySQLConnectOptions()
                .setDatabase("mysql")
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setSslMode(SslMode.DISABLED)
                .setPort(3306)
                .setUser("root")
                .setPassword("password");

        return Pool.pool(vertx, options, new PoolOptions());
    }


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Uni<String> hello() {
        return getPool().query("toto").execute().onItem().transform(unused -> "Hello, world!");
    }
}


Once the native compilation is completed, it generates the following error:
2024-09-24 17:30:41,502 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) HTTP Request to /hello failed, error id: d66d3141-5eb9-4072-9bbb-95209474b253-1: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: No implementations of interface io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver found that accept connection options io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions@58a8452
        at io.vertx.sqlclient.Pool.pool(Pool.java:86)
        at io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Pool.pool(Pool.java:102)
        at fr.cgi.learninghub.swarm.GreetingResource.getPool(GreetingResource.java:36)
        at fr.cgi.learninghub.swarm.GreetingResource.hello(GreetingResource.java:43)
        at fr.cgi.learninghub.swarm.GreetingResource$quarkusrestinvoker$hello_d1fd18c65b32335d71a4b7282527a960c5fc08f2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:23)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:10)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:40)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:358)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:347)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1285)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:68)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:37)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:86)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:182)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:158)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:67)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:30)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:328)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:164)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:174)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:159)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.onHttpRequestChannelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:158)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:82)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.java:124)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:289)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:289)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@21.0.4/java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1596)
        at java.base@21.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:896)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:872)

I tried to fix the issue based on the page https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips, but I wasn't successful. Here’s what I tried:
Adding the annotations @RegisterForReflection and @RegisterForProxy to the class in question:
@RegisterForReflection(targets = {MySQLDriver.class, MySQLConnectOptions.class, MySQLPool.class})
@RegisterForProxy(targets = {Driver.class})


Adding the following configuration to the pom.xml:

<quarkus.native.additional-build-args>--initialize-at-run-time=io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions\,io.vertx.mysqlclient.spi.MySQLDriver\,io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver\,io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>


Adding a reflect-config.json file in the src/main/resources/ folder:

[
  {
    "name": "io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  },
  {
    "name": "io.vertx.mysqlclient.spi.MySQLDriver",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  },
  {
    "name": "io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  },
  {
    "name": "io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  }
]


Adding a BuildSteps class:

public class BuildSteps {

    @BuildStep
    NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem proxies() {
        return new NativeImageProxyDefinitionBuildItem("io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions",
                "io.vertx.mysqlclient.spi.MySQLDriver", "io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver", "io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool");
    }
}

None of these attempts worked. I have no more ideas on how to solve the problem. Can anyone help me?
Thanks,
SLedunois
Update:
Here is the pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test.native</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-native</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.14.4</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.3.1</surefire-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.native.additional-build-args>--initialize-at-run-time=io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions\,io.vertx.mysqlclient.spi.MySQLDriver\,io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver\,io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-mysql-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-builder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-core-deployment</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                            <goal>native-image-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.native.enabled>true</quarkus.native.enabled>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

EDIT: I finally fixed the issue refactoring my code. The working code is:
    private Pool getPool() {
        var options = new MySQLConnectOptions()
                .setDatabase("mysql")
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setSslMode(SslMode.DISABLED)
                .setPort(3306)
                .setUser("root")
                .setPassword("password");

        return MySQLBuilder.pool()
                .connectingTo(options)
                .using(vertx)
                .build();
    }


I'm not sure about that, it works well in jar mode. There is a dependency that is removed during the native compilation.

Here is the import in the GreetingResource class:
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForProxy;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;
import io.vertx.mutiny.mysqlclient.MySQLPool;
import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Pool;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.SslMode;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.spi.MySQLDriver;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.PoolOptions;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.spi.Driver;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;


Can you update the question with a snippet of the POM file ? I'd like to understand if the Reactive MySQL extension is used.

Also, I would like to understand what you're trying to achieve with this. It seems you would like to customize Pool creation, and there is a solution for this: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#customizing-pool-creation

I just updated the post with the pom.xml.

What I'm trying to do is the following: I have a database with a table containing databases. From these, I open a connection and run a maintenance query. That's why I need to create connections dynamically.

@tsegismont I fixed the code and updated the issue. Thanks
